# Declare route on runtime using Express (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to declare routes after a DB call during runtime?

What I'd like to do is something like this in my `server.js`

```
function init() {
 let names = getFromDb();
 for (let name in names) {
    // register route '/name'
 }
}
init();
```

So if someone calls `localhost/knownName` it will serve index.html but if someone calls `localhost/unknownName` it will return 404.